# Increase upload size without acces to php.ini

Tags: php

I want to increase the upload size of my PHP scripts.
From some google searches I have learned you do this by changing the `upload_max_filesize`parameters in your php.ini.

Unfortunatly I use one.com for webhosting, and it does not give me access to my php.ini.

Can I change this parameter later?
I was thinking of adding a second php.ini or to change the parameter on the index page.

Comment: This has been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2185500/5845530

Comment: Please do your research before asking a certain question

Comment: check here :--->  http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-apache-increase-php-upload-limit/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.htaccess` with these code:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 30M // Set upload max filesize to 30MB
php_value post_max_size 30M // Set post max size to 30MB
```

### Note

> Your provider has to be enabled `Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support` for using `php_value`! Very technical documentation can you find here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/dso.html

Answer (score 0):

You can change through your `.htaccess` if you are using Apache. Add this line to your `.htaccess`

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 100M
```